# Using android crop-library

Tags: android, geometry, android-library

I wanna use android crop library(https://github.com/biokys/cropimage) with custom settings.

Making an example circle line that doesn't show on the cropped image is my goal.

[image]

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: checkout [Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) library, it has good customization options.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get the cropped image

```
Bitmap newbitmap = thecropedBitmap;
```

And once you get the newbitmap you can easily crop **again** but this time you are going to get the circle using the following method:

```
public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    //Bitmap _bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 60, 60, false);
    //return _bmp;
    return output;
}
```

Add this line:

```
newbitmap = getCroppedBitmap(newbitmap);
```